# Раскрытие при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
jQuery(function() {
  var c = $(".content").size();
  x = 5;
  $('.content:lt(' + x + ')').fadeIn();
  $('.show-hide').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = (x + 5 <= c) ? x + 999 : c;
    $('.content:lt(' + x + ')').slideDown(500);
    $('.content:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    $('.show-hide').hide();

  });
});
```

В общем, сейчас работает так, но если на странице будет несколько (.content) как быть?
Получается сейчас так, что отображает один (.content) а все остальные скрыты вообще, но при нажатии на (.show-hide) раскрываются сразу все.
Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы работало все по отдельности и на странице можно было размещать несколько .content

Comment: Сделайте разные .content, .content2, . content2 и. тд и И для каждого отдельный ява скрипт.

Comment: Этот вариант сразу понятен, но это не вариант решения проблемы.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, это точно решение:)

Comment: Тоже не вариант,сейчас весь код добавлю, чтобы было наглядно видно,что и как работает

Comment: Я привёл рабочий пример того что ты хотел, ты просто поменяй класс и все:)

Comment: нет,не выйдет так

Comment: Можно аргументировать? почему у меня в документе все вышло а у вас с тем же кодом нет? в чём ошибка?

Comment: Иван, опишите каждый свой шаг вслух (даже письменно можно здесь), каждую строчку, и станет понятно, почему так происходит.

Comment: сделаю еще проще, а то будет долго переписывать весь код заново

Comment: https://akar-groupp.com/professionalnaya-perepodgotovka/

Comment: https://akar-groupp.com/professionalnaya-perepodgotovka/

Comment: Прямо на проекте в реальном времени можешь посмотреть, чтобы уже код сюда не переписывать

Comment: Во 1 очень тормозит сайт, оптимизация на 0 , а во вторых куда смотреть то? я вам скинул рабочий пример , подставьте его на свой сайт, поменяйте классы и готово, не пойму в чем проблема.

Comment: Прям интересно стало))что у вас там тормозит ,все загружается на отлично, с учетом того как сайт нормально так нагружен.Оптимизация проведена тоеж

Comment: Я сейчас серьёзно, вы тестировали сайт на разных устройствах? Нагруженность сайта не оправдание , почитайте о lazy-loading.

Comment: Тестирование , все летает, вы честно говоря меня даже удивили сейчас,проблема наверное с вашей стороны.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь в этом, на котором в Chrome достаточно неприятно тормозит: 
Проц: AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 555 Processor
Графика: AMD RS780
8гб ОЗУ.

Comment: Заинтересовал, напиши пожалуйста мне https://t.me/v_kubik

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения проблемы:

`html`:

```
<div class='closed' onclick='showCloseItem(this)'>
   asd
<div class='hiddenItem'>  hiddenItem 1</div>
</div>
<div class='closed' onclick='showCloseItem(this)'>
   asd
   <div class='hiddenItem'>  hiddenItem 2</div>
</div>
<div class='closed' onclick='showCloseItem(this)'>
   asd
   <div class='hiddenItem'>  hiddenItem 3</div>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
.closed .hiddenItem {
  display: none;
}

.opened .hiddenItem {
  display: block;
}
```

js:

```
function showCloseItem(item) {
        $(item).toggleClass('closed', 'opened');
};
```